# Vagrant Access index.php

Tags: vagrant

I believe this is the right place to ask.

First, I've installed VirtualBox and Vagrant.
After that, I've cd'd to this: https://github.com/LearnWebCode/vagrant-lamp (downloaded zip, extracted folder)
Then after running *vagrant up*, I've reached the **Congratulations** page through IP http://192.168.56.101/

After that, I've set an easy-to-read URL in the hosts file, and able to run it but it leads to the *Congratulations* page and not the index.php's *Hello World*.

Any idea how to rectify? Not sure if this is part of the cause, this came up during the first set-up: *The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status*

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, the URL MUST be fictional-university.test for it to access the index.php, it cannot work otherwise.